# How to overwrite ports defined in application.properties in integration tests after testcontainer started?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testcontainers

Assume I want to integration test code relying on a JPA datasource in a Spring Boot 2.x application with a PostgreSQL `testcontainer` (great tool for managing Docker containers from within test classes with one or few more lines of code). Assume further that I'm managing the ports (included in the JDBC URL) in `application.properties`, e.g.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://user-service-postgres:5432/user_service
```

In the integration test I create testcontainers with

```
@Rule
PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer();
```

In a preparation method I can access the value I want to set for `spring.datasource.url` with

```
postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl()
```

How to tell Spring Boot in the test to use that URL instead of the one specified in `application.properties`.

I'd like to stick to my property files in order to minimize changes, but I'm thankful for other approaches including an explanation why they're superior or necessary as well.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually override the property from within your Spring-boot test by using `ContextConfiguration` and `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Override the property - define a static inner class:

```java
  static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
      TestPropertyValues
          .of("spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl())
          .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
  }
```

`ApplicationContextInitializer` can be used for programmatically initializing a Spring context before context refresh. Now, wire up the context initializer class by annotating at test class level with `ContextConfiguration`:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = Initializer.class)
```

Docs:

[ApplicationContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html)

[ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html)

Comment: However, the question was. to change ports when running Postgresql in Testcontainers и and the question is still open.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't the OP's question and this answer has been accepted by them too. I don't see how it's still open then. Your question is different as I can see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132686/how-can-i-set-the-port-for-postgresql-when-using-testcontainers. I urge you to continue your discussion there.

Answer (score 10):

Since Spring Framework 5.2.5 (Spring Boot 2.2.6) this setup is now even simpler as we can use the `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation and don't have to write and register a custom initializer.

Assuming you use the JUnit 5 dependency of Testcontainers, your test can look like the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class ExampleIntegrationTests {

    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void dataSourceProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
    }

}
```

You can read more about this new feature [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/27/dynamicpropertysource-in-spring-framework-5-2-5-and-spring-boot-2-2-6). I've also covered the different application properties setup ways (depending on Spring Boot and JUnit version) in a [dedicated Testcontainers guide](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/).

Comment: I don't read the question that way. Why would you want to change the port of a running container?

Comment: To configure the database manager in IntelliJ idea in advance and not change the port each time, since it is allocated dynamically. This is inconvenient.

Comment: I can see that you have an open question for exactly this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132686/how-can-i-set-the-port-for-postgresql-when-using-testcontainers) - I guess it's better to continue the discussion there

Comment: I haven't received an answer there yet