# How can I set the port for Postgresql when using Testcontainers?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, java-11, testcontainers

Sometimes I need to install a port for **Postgresql**, which I run for tests in a container. But the Test container the developer command ofTestcontainers removed this feature. But somewhere there is a workaround solution, through the settings, but I can't find it. Who has any ideas or information on how to do this ?

```java
public class ContainerConfig {

    private static final PostgreSQLContainer postgresSQLContainer;

    static {
        DockerImageName postgres = DockerImageName.parse("postgres:13.1");

        postgresSQLContainer = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer(postgres)
                .withDatabaseName("test")
                .withUsername("root")
                .withPassword("root")
                .withReuse(true);

        postgresSQLContainer.start();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static PostgreSQLContainer getPostgresSQLContainer() {
        return postgresSQLContainer;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @DynamicPropertySource
   public static void registerPgProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry propertyRegistry) {

        propertyRegistry.add("integration-tests-db", getPostgresSQLContainer()::getDatabaseName);
        propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", getPostgresSQLContainer()::getUsername);
        propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", getPostgresSQLContainer()::getPassword);
        propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url",  getPostgresSQLContainer()::getJdbcUrl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Add port binding with `withCreateContainerCmdModifier`.

```
static {
    int containerPort = 5432 ;
    int localPort = 5432 ;
    DockerImageName postgres = DockerImageName.parse("postgres:13.1");
    postgreDBContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(postgres)
            .withDatabaseName("test")
            .withUsername("root")
            .withPassword("root")
            .withReuse(true)
            .withExposedPorts(containerPort)
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostConfig(
                    new HostConfig().withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(localPort), new ExposedPort(containerPort)))
            ));
    postgreDBContainer.start();
}
```

Comment: I have gotten an error - If I set port 5437 or another (for example, 32700) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested port (5432) is not mapped. If I set port 5432 , an error message comes out that: (48165926feea259777b85edc2a6e9567516841a4121ae924a6836e46d816ffb0): Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated"}

Comment: I have updated the answer. The container port should be 5432 for postgresql. If changing local port  shows error message 'port already allocated', check you may be running another container on the same port. You can view it by docker ps and stop it by docker stop [CONTAINER ID].

Comment: that's the thing, I didn't want to be tied to port 5432 . I would like to allocate the port myself. what I think is necessary at the moment